# How to ignore duplicate values in range loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I start with this input:

```
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    print(i,j)
```

I get this output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

How do I design the For loop so that I do not get reverse duplicate "coordinates" such as (0,1) and (1,0) or (1,2) and (2,1)?

The output I want from the nested For loop is:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work, just cut the second loop short so that the first number is always greater than or equal to the second:

```
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(i+1):
    print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate these sorts of non-duplicate coordinates would be to use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). For example:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

results = combinations_with_replacement(range(3), 2)
print(*results, sep='\n')
# (0, 0)
# (0, 1)
# (0, 2)
# (1, 1)
# (1, 2)
# (2, 2)
```